# NTLM authentication token invalid only from Apache HttpClient

Tags: android, iis, apache-httpclient-4.x, ntlm, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm trying to use NTLM authentication in HttpClient 4.3.3 as follows:

```
BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), AuthScope.ANY_REALM, "ntlm");
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(authScope, new NTCredentials(username + ":" + password));
context.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
```

I see it negotiating NTLM state up to `MSG_TYPE3_GENERATED` before the server fails with `404.1` and logs `The token supplied to the function is invalid (0x80090308)`.

It's a local account and not a domain account so SPN is not an issue. I've tried all combinations of domain and workstation names. Only Windows Authentication is enabled and only the NTLM provider is selected within it for this folder.

It works in the Android stock browser when I just enter the username and password in the prompt.

Comment: First off, are you sure the browser does not fall back onto another auth scheme (digest or plain) behind the scene?

Comment: Yes I've disabled everything else on the folder in IIS and enabled Failed Request Tracing. The browser successfully negotiates NTLM, and the only WWW-Authorization header advertised by the server is NTLM.

Comment: Fair enough. Please try to use CIFS engine instead of the internal one as a next step and see if that makes any difference http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/ntlm.html

Comment: Have you tried using the NTCredentials constructor that allows you to specify the domain of the user?  In my work with HttpClient 4.3.5 I've successfully used that with a null for the `workstation` parameter.